# What version of Silverlight works with the latest 10.7 release?

Tags: macos, crash, silverlight

Can you install Microsoft Silverlight from microsoft.com and are you able to open the Preferences without it crashing?

I'm trying to isolate this problem, and it could be a Mac problem, or a Silverlight problem.

I am hearing that it works fine on some people's Macs and not on others, but there is no obvious pattern to it.  It could be that it doesn't work on particular versions of Mac OS X, or it could be that 3rd party software that some people use, messes up Silverlight.

Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac lab to try it out on several computers so I would really appreciate some feedback on this if you have a Mac.

If you have a PowerPC based chipset or a Mac with a version older than 10.6 (Snow Leopard) then you probably should not bother testing this because Silverlight only supports Intel chipsets and 10.6 and up.

If you are able to test out the latest version of Silverlight 5, please list your exact Mac OS X version, and what version of Silverlight installed fine for you.

I'm wondering what version of silverlight works best with Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight - 5.0.61118.0

MacBookPro9,2

50 - 10.7.5(11G63)

5 - 10.8.2(12A269)

**Silverlight Prefs come up just fine.**

**Installed programs:**

Chrome 24

Safari 6

Firefox 18

All updates

iLife

iWork

Office 2008

Adobe CS3

VLC

Smart Notebook

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I'm going to leave this open for a few days and if I don't get any more answers I'll mark this the answer.

Comment: Ill run my Snow Leopard lab tomorrow so you can have a bit more data.

Answer (score 0):

No. I get a crash.   Have latest Silverlight 5.1.20125.0 and 10.8.4 on a Mac Pro (mid 2008) with 16GB and Radeon 5770.  Very frustrating.  Crashes in Safari and Chrome.  Have not tried FF but have no real hope.

Comment: Welcome to SO, sadly, it's not meant for open discussion like a typical forum (can do that in the comments, or in the chat function)

Comment: In fairness to Chad, this is basically what the OP asked for. The question isn't really formulated in an ideal way for a Stack Exchange site...